# Incorrect encoding name syntax

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, encoding, xml-declaration

Code:

```
declare @filedata xml 
select @filedata = BulkColumn from openrowset(bulk 'E:\Scripts\apc.xml',single_blob) x;
```

the above is my code for which I got the error:

> Msg 9442, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 XML parsing: line 1, character 38, incorrect encoding name syntax

could anyone help me with how I can resolve this? I can't understand where the syntax is wrong.

Comment: It's complaining about the XML syntax. We would need to see the *XML* to have a hope of pointing out the problem to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL-Server cannot import any kind of encoding...

You are importing this file as `BLOB`, this is just a bunch of bytes. This must be interpreted as a data type SQL Server knows.

You can either try to declare your variable as `VARCHAR(MAX)` or as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and hope, that the content of this variable is what you expect.

In this case you can cut off the entire xml-declaration (`<?xml blah?>`) using `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` or `STUFF`. Alternatively you can use `REPLACE` to set a different value to your `encoding="blah"`. Use `UTF-8` if `VARCHAR` worked for you, or `UTF-16` in case of `NVARCHAR`.

If this does not help, you must change the file on disc **before** you read it. Best is `utf-16`, which can be read into XML directly. But don't forget to write this into the `encoding` or to strip off the declaration.

Comment: @B21: Better than thanks would be to [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thank you.